# Ubuntu Bootloader Help

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, bootloader, bios

I'm thinking of installing Ubuntu on my PC (quite old) alongside Windows 8.1. My **BIOS mode is Legacy BIOS** so no worries about UEFI settings.

I have a separate partition (**Local Disk E: 30GB**) for  Ubuntu installation (**My Windows is installed on Local Disk C:**).

My questions are :

1. Where should I install my GRUB bootloader so that I will get the
   option of choosing between Windows and Ubuntu every time I  boot?
2. Should I delete the Local Disk E: I set aside for Ubuntu from within
   windows and leave it as unallocated space?
3. What is **/** and **swap** and what should I do about them?

P.S : I don't want to mess around with Local Disk C: as much as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't describe whether your E: and C: are the partitions belong to the same physical hard disk. Let's me assume these two partitions are on the same physical hard disk. Please note the following answer is based on this assumption.

1. You don't need to worry about the grub location because grub-update (one of the grub tools) will find out the bootable systems including Windows and add them in the grub menu. You could choose the OS system you want to boot at the grub menu.
2. No. Ubuntu installer will delete the partition for you during installation.
3. **/** is the root directory of your Ubuntu(or say, Linux). It means the most top of all the directories in your Ubuntu systems.

   **swap** is a hard disk memory space to help the real memory to store data. You don't need to use swap if you memory is large (more than 4G)

You don't need to worry about how to set up the / and swap during installing Ubuntu because the Ubuntu installer could set up them for you automatically.

Comment: Yes E: and C: belong to the same physical hard disk (160 GB). My RAM is 4 GB so I assume I don't need swap. I set aside 30GB for Ubuntu so, I guess that's enough for both / and even swap.

Comment: In my experience 4GB is enough for my daily tasks. You could make and add your own swap anytime after your installation. Use free -m to realize your usage of the memory and decide whether you want to manually add more swap.